# Outcome of a Tournament (Combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

I'd like a tip or a hint in this elementary problem:

Three Tennis Players A, B and C will compete in a tournament with 10 rounds (one play per round). Two players face each every round and the winner faces the third player (that did not participate the round) in the next round. The winner of the last play (the tenth round) is the tournament's champion. In the initial round A and B face each other. Therefore, a possible outcome is the sequence ACCAAABBBC, with C declared champion. Determine the number of possible outcomes to the sequence of games in which B is champion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Work backwards from $B$ as the final winner (round 10). The previous winner (round 9) could have been any of $A,B,C$. Suppose it was $A$. That means $A$ played $B$ in round 10. In *this* case there are now two possibilities for previous winner (round 8). But if the round 9 winner was $B$, there are three possibilities for the previous (round 8) winner.

Comment: @JonasGomes +1 Nice problem. Unless you let me know, I will assume you have finished it off with that hint. Perhaps you should at least add the answer somewhere (for the benefit of others) - you can answer your own question!

Comment: Thanks @almagest! I finished it off and I'll add the answer later today!

Comment: @almagest For the answer, I get that 1) we need n-1 games in total to eliminate n-1 players 2) there is $C^{n}_{2}$ way to match 2 players.
What I don't understand is why the answer is $C^{n}_{2}(n-1)$?

isn't that $C^{n}_{2}$ is only for the first round when we still have n players? for the second round, if A and B still stay in the game, but the number of the plays in the game has been reduced to 0.5n, so $C^{0.5n}_{2}$ is probability for A to meet B? and if any of A or B got knocked out, they will never meet?

Answer (score 0):

Using @almagest hint I was able to solve the problem, with some generalization:

The generalized problem is: How many ways can $B$ win the game in the nth round?

For $n=1$ and $n=2$ the answer is $1$
($B$ and $BB$)

Suppose that we know how many ways can $B$ win the game in the nth round and lets call that number $W(n)$, so that $W(1)=W(2)=1$

To calculate $W(n)$ it is sufficient to note that, if $B$ wins the nth game, then we have three possibilities: $A, B$ or $C$ won the (n-1)th game.

If $A$ won the (n-1)th game, it was playing against $C$ (otherwise $B$ wouldnt play the n-th game). So that in the (n-2)th game, either $A$ played against $B$  (and $A$ won) or $C$ played against $B$ (and $C$ won), but the different ways it could have happened is precisely $W(n-2)$

If $C$ won the (n-1)th game, it was playing against $A$, so that in the (n-2)th game either $C$ played against $B$ or $A$ played against $B$ and, as before, there are $W(n-1)$ ways of doing that.

If $B$ won the (n-1)th game there are $W(n-1)$ ways of doing that, so we have

$W(n) = W(n-1) + 2W(n-2)$

With $W(1)=W(2)=1$

Solving the linear recurrence we get

$W(n) = \frac{1}{3} \left ( 2^n + (-1)^{n+1} \right)$

And then $W(10) = 341$